# Mongodb: Query to see if a field contains an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I seem to have some documents from an old schema in my mongodb collection.  The field is supposed to be a string, but some old documents contain arrays.  This is causing problems with indexing.

Is there a query I can perform to identify which documents contain arrays (not strings) in this field?

Answer (score 1):

It the field is an array then you can determine by using [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

```js
db.collection.find( { "possible_array": { "$type" : 4 } } )
```

Then basically change those to be the type that you want.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work for me (no results). But you did point me in the right direction: `{ $where : "Array.isArray(this.possible_array)" }` worked great.  I think the first didn't work because according to that page _This query will select all documents in the inventory collection where the tags array contains an element that is itself an array._ If you want to add this other method to the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @UpTheCreek It does depend on the situation indeed, as is pointed out on the manual page that was linked to. I almost added it in to the body as a reference other than the link should have been enough.

Comment: But it's not possible to use $type in this way (to distinguish between arrays and non arrays) because (from docs) `If the field holds an array, the $type operator performs the type check against the array elements and not the field.`  So sorry, but I can't accept the answer as it stands.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Is the the field actually an array or does it "contain" an array. I am very aware of the documentation (since I provided the link, and the explaination) but what is it you are actually asking? If the the field queried actually is an array then it responds to `$type` as shown. If you are looking for something that might possibly "contain" an array then you can revert to the JavaScript test. Why ask the question if you cannot accept the response of someone pointing you towards something you clearly did not know? If you want to say you knew that then why ask anyway? Fair? Answered.

Comment: No need to get snarky.  I obviously didn't know.  Your answer as it stands doesn't solve the problem.  I've since found a solution that worked (you pointed me in the right direction) and I just suggested that you add this to your answer before I accept it.  You don't have to of course, and I certainly don't think this is worth getting stressed about.